# Do I need a neural network or graph database like neo4j for suggestion engine?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neo4j

I am building a simple recommendation/suggestion engine for a demo application which maintains a list of people. For each person, it keeps track of their food habits with the following preferences:

1. Diet type: Vegetarian/non-vegetarian/vegan
2. Cuisine likings: Indian, Mexican, Italian, etc. (a person can like more than one)
3. Type of meals with exact time: Breakfast, lunch, supper, dinner
4. Specialized diets: Keto, Blood-group type, Atkins, etc.
5. Favorite vegetables: Spinach, Broccoli, etc.
6. Food allergy requirements
7. Location - City, area, street, etc.

Once this data is available to the system, I need to build a simple suggestion engine -

1. For any person chosen, suggest 10 other people who are most compatible in terms of food habits.
2. For a group of people chosen (say x, max 5), suggest x + 10 (here 15) people from the system in such a way that each person in the chosen group has compatible habit with at least one other person. Order of people in a group doesn't matter.

My understanding here is that I don't need future predictions on unknown data and thus really no need for machine learning. All I need is suggestions based on statistical compatibility of existing data set. The rules are mostly based on relationships that people have with their food habits.

Is my understanding correct? Is this problem entirely solvable with graph database like Neo4j? Or do I really to build a Neural model for this using Tensorflow?

Comment: Your question is subjective and thus getting down and close votes. However there is enough facts to get it back over the line to being objective. If this were my question I would rewrite it so that you don't get the close and down votes.

Comment: @GuyCoder, That is strange. It is not really opinion based and certainly not a recommendation. But thanks for the tip. Let me see how I can change.

Comment: It is not how you see the question but how the others who vote see the question. Or for another TV reference, [Survivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_(U.S._TV_series)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to know which one to choose is to answer this more specific question. Is the data open world or [closed world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption).

If you are an original [Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Corbomite_Maneuver#Plot) fan then think of it like how Spock would inference and needs all of the data before being able to answer ([Closed world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption)) or Captain Kirk who doesn't need all of the information before answering (Open World).

Seeing that you have all of the data needed before giving a solution I would say that you have a closed world problem and this should use Neo4j.

However being a fan of Logic programming, my personal preference would be to use either Prolog, specifically [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) or [Mercury](https://www.mercurylang.org/).

Comment: Well, +1 for a fabulous Star Trek reference (in what is otherwise an off-topic question)...!

Comment: Using Prolog seems a good option. I haven't thought about it previously.